# awk - dynamically format tab-separated columns

Tags: awk, csv, columns, gawk

I have a file with dynamic length columns (four) separated with tabs (a column can have have spaces)

```
COL1    COL2 COL2 COL2  COL3 COL3       COL4
COL1    COL2 COL2       COL3    COL4 COL4
COL1 COL1       COL2 COL2       COL3    COL4 COL4 COL4
```

I 'd like to format it dynamically with printf in awk? I can format it with fixed adjustments:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}; {printf "%-10s %-10s %-15s %-15s\n", $1,$3,$4,$2}' test
COL1       COL3 COL3  COL4            COL2 COL2 COL2
COL1       COL3       COL4 COL4       COL2 COL2
COL1 COL1  COL3       COL4 COL4 COL4  COL2 COL2
```

Comment: How about `column -t file`?

Answer (score 4):

in bash, using `column`

```
$ column -s $'\t' -t file.tsv
col1       col2 col2 col2  col3 col3  col4
col1       col2 col2       col3       col4 col4
col1 col1  col2 col2       col3       col4 col4 col4
```

`column -t` uses 2 spaces to separate the columns

---

With awk, I'd write

```
awk -F '\t' -v cols=4 '
    NR == FNR {
        for (i=1; i<=cols; i++) 
            if (NR == 1 || length($i) > w[i]) 
                w[i] = length($i)
        next
    }
    {
        for (i=1; i<=cols; i++) 
            printf "%-*s%s", w[i], $i, (i == cols ? ORS : FS) 
    }
' file.tsv file.tsv
```

Where I"m processing the file twice: first to find the max wideths for each column, then again to reformat the file. I use a tab to separate the columns in the output.

```
col1            col2 col2 col2  col3 col3       col4
col1            col2 col2       col3            col4 col4
col1 col1       col2 col2       col3            col4 col4 col4
```